# Maximum of a function $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: complex-analysis, maxima-minima

If there is a function $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$, namely $ f(Z)$. Is it correct to search minima of the function by demanding $\frac{\partial f} {\partial Z}$ = 0 , where Z is a complex number?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy - if they had $\dfrac{df}{dz}$ that would be correct, but $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ and its partner $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \overline z}$ are definable whenever $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ exist, where $z = x+iy$.